# Tensorflow maximum recursion depth exceed only with import

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to start a Tensorflow project, I can install it, but when I do `import tensorflow as tf` it gives me a error. I'm using Python 3.8, Cuda CudNN...

The error:

```
File "C:\Users\Felipe Garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])

File "C:\Users\Felipe Garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 301, in find_module

encoding = tokenize.detect_encoding(file.readline)[0]

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

This is only the end of the error, but the rest of the error is the same and is very long.

Thanks for all.

Comment: what tf version?

Comment: The version is python 3.8.3

Comment: by `tf` I mean what `tensorflow` version? and how did you install it?

Comment: I'm using 1.12.0

Comment: I use this command: `python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: If this specific version of tensorflow is not a requirement try upgrading to tensorflow 2.x using `pip install tensorflow==2.2`. Does this solve the issue?

Comment: It gives me this error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2`

Comment: use `pip3 install tensorflow==2.2` instead

Comment: It gives me the same error 

Comment: try `pip3 uninstall tensorflow` then `pip3 install tensorflow`

Comment: Nothing, same error.

Comment: what same error?

Comment: This: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow`